# Camunda Rest API: Cannot fetch and lock an External Task for a Tenant

Tags: camunda

I have a Process Instance that was started by the Tenant *949*.

[image]

I tried to fetch and lock that Task, like described here: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/reference/rest/external-task/fetch/

Here is the Body of the Request:

```
{"workerId":"testUser","maxTasks":1,"usePriority":false,
"topics":[
    {"topicName":"archive-document","tenantIdIn":["949"],"lockDuration":10000,"localVariables":true,"deserializeValues":false}
]}
```

I don't get any Task with it.

The same request works if the Process Instance is started without a Tenant and fetched accordingly.

Do I miss something, or is this a Bug of Camunda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Authentication.

I had a different User to start the process and to fetch the Task.

And this User had no rights to fetch the Task for this Tenant.

Answer (score 1):

Have you attempted to simply do a query to first retrieve the task? (Rather than attempting to fetch it and lock it?) You could use this endpoint: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/reference/rest/external-task/get-query/.

You may also want to query the runtime database directly using SQL. Your External Task would be in the ACT_RU_EXT_TASK table and would have a TOPIC_NAME_ defined within it (as well as a TENANT_ID_).

Comment: thanks for this suggestion - it helped me to locate the problem.